How can I make it so that a user outside a conversation can write directly in a whatsapp conversation, using the whatsapp api?
Look I have the following problem. i am new with whatsapp api meta: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/
I have a bot that answers customers, it needs the conversation to reach a certain point to be answered by an executive, as if it were a call center. The way I had thought about it is to make a replica of the conversation in a web app, so that the executive answers it from there. However my development team does not want it that way, they want the executive who assigns the bot to communicate directly from whatsapp in that conversation. I don't know how to accomplish this, I would appreciate if anyone has an idea on how to do this.
I am desperate for help, I have been looking for a while to figure this out, to no avail. My development team says everything can be done and they need it soon.
